# find length of an arc of parabola

Tags: calculus, arc-length

Actually small question, but i need also small hints

So I have the canonical equation:
$$y^2=2px \space (0 \le x \le x_0)$$

As far as I know there's the following integral:

$$\int^b_a\sqrt{1+f'(y)^2}dy$$

but should I simplify the function like this?

$$y = \sqrt{2px}$$

And only then find $y'$ ?

Comment: With the integral you've written down, it's writing $x=f(y)$ and then the $y$-integral $\int_a^b \sqrt{1+f'(y)^2}\,dy$.

Comment: I prefer to write $s=\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1+(\frac{dx}{dy})^2} dy$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either way same result. We can take

$$ x=f(y )$$

or

$$ y= g(x) $$

Prime denotes differentiation wrt other independent variable

$$x'=f'(y )$$

or

$$y'= g'(x) $$

$$s = \int \sqrt{1+ f'(y)^2} dy  = \int \sqrt{1+ g'(x)^2} dx$$